# Plotting a difference curve involving the reference smooth

Tags: mgcv

I'm wondering if there is a way to plot a difference curve for two smooths involving the intercept.

Here is a summary of the model smooths.

```r
s(percent)                 
  s(percent):x1x2voiced.D    
  s(percent):x1x2voiceless.f 
  s(percent):x1x2voiced.G    
  s(percent):x1x2voiceless.h 
  s(percent):x1x2voiceless.s 
  s(percent):x1x2voiceless.S 
  s(percent):x1x2voiceless.T 
  s(percent):x1x2voiceless.x 
  s(percent):x1x2voiceless.X-
  s(percent):x1x2voiced.z
```

The following code (from `itsadug`) works fine.

```r
plot_diff(m1, view='percent', comp=list(x1x2=c('voiced.D', 'voiceless.f')))
```

But I'm interested also in other contrasts such as `s(percent)` vs. `s(percent):x1x2voiced.G`. Is there a way to include the first smooth `s(percent)` in the `comp` call?

I'm aware of this code (from `mgcViz`) which works fine:

```r
plotDiff(s1 = sm(b, 1), s2 = sm(b, 2)) + l_ciPoly() + l_fitLine() + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 2)
```

But I'd love something following the same approach as `itsadug` in order to integrate the output with other functions such as `get_smooths_difference()` from `tidymv`.

Comment: What does your model structure look like? - show the `gam()` call please. Are these using the ordered factor trick to get a reference smooth plus smooth differences?

Comment: Yes, I am using ordered factors. Here it is.

`bam(val ~ x1x2 +
s(percent, bs= "cr", k=10) +
s(percent, bs= "cr", k=10, by=x1x2) +
s(percent, stim, bs="fs", m=1, k=10, by=x1x2)+
s(percent, stim, bs="fs", m=1, k=10)+
s(percent, word, bs="fs", m=1, k=10),   
data = kurt_gam_aa_ini,
AR.start=kurt_gam_aa_ini$start.event,
method = "fREML",
discrete=T,
family = "scat",
nthread=8)))`

Comment: `s(percent)` refers to the reference level of `x1x2`, so can't you just include that in the `comp` definition? Something like `comp = list(x1x2, = c(levels(kurt_gam_aa_ini$x1x2)[1L], "voiced.G"))`. The way the differencing works is that it generates data over `percent` for the 2 levels of the factor mentioned, all other covariates are held constant at typical values, then it `predict()`s using `type = "lpmatrix"` to get matrix Xp and then we take the rows of Xp that correspond to the first level, and rows of Xp that correspond to the other level we are comparing with, then...

Comment: it subtracts these two sub matrices from one another to yield the difference Xp matrix, we then multiply `%*%` by the model coefficients to get the actual difference between the two smooths, and we compute a standard error for the difference using the `vcov()` of the fitted model. So the trick is just I think to know how to specify the data that you want, and in this case it's which levels of `x1x2` you want to compare.

Comment: I tried this code `plot_diff(m1, view='percent', comp=list(x1x2=c(levels(m1$x1x2)[1L], "voiced.G")))` , but it produced this error `Error in get_difference(model, comp = comp, cond = cond, se = ifelse(se >  : Provide two levels for x1x2 to calculate difference.`

Comment: I guess the issue is just in specifying the data I want to use as your noted, which is something I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I figured it out following Gavin's comment.
Here is the answer for anybody else who might come later looking for the answer.

This code extracts the reference level for the ordered factors.

`plot_diff(cog_ini__aa_m2, view='percent', comp=list(x1x2=c(cog_ini__aa_m2[["xlevels"]]$x1x2[1], "voiceless.X-")))`
[image]

And here is how I fed it to `tidymv` for extra customizations.

`get_smooths_difference(cog_ini__aa_m2, percent, list(x1x2=c(cog_ini__aa_m2[["xlevels"]]$x1x2[1], "voiceless.X-")))-> inter_diff`

`inter_diff %>% ggplot(aes(percent, difference, group = group)) + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), colour = "#8f5f3f") + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = CI_lower, ymax = CI_upper, fill = sig_diff), alpha = 0.3) + geom_line(aes(colour = sig_diff), size = 1) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("#e35760", "#6f849c")) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#e35760", "#6f849c")) + labs(colour = "significant", fill = "significant") + theme(legend.position = "top")`

This produces the plot I'm looking for.
[image]

Thanks Gavin for your time and help!